# rangeOfString to detect whether a "." is pressed twice

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am a novice in Programming and have just started Objective C. I have created a text field in which I want to allow a "." to be entered only once! From what I understand, rangeOfString should be able to do this.

```
-(IBAction)floatingPoint:(UIButton *) sender {

    NSString *floatingPoint = [sender currentTitle];
    NSRange range = [floatingPoint rangeOfString:@"."];

    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        self.display.text = 
            [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:floatingPoint];
    }
}
```

From what I understand the code floatingPoint rangeOfString:@"." would check for "." in currentTitle and if it is not found should append this string with a "."

But this is not happening, no decimal point is being entered. If I enter only 
`self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:floatingPoint];` 
then the text field allows more than 1 decimal points to be entered.
Sorry if I described the problem incorrectly, I am new to all this stuff and this has just begun to sink in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking the button's title for a `.`.  You probably set the button's title to `.` in your nib, so of course it always contains a `.`!

You need to check your text field's text for a `.` instead.  Try this:

```
NSRange range = [self.display.text rangeOfString:floatingPoint];
```

Comment: Works beautifully, Thanks a million! What a foolish mistake:)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this would be to add `UITextField` delegate to your `.h` then use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`
check if the string already contains a `.` and return `NO` if it does and `YES` if it doesnt.

Comment: I will try using this method and report back if successful! Thank You for your answer.